# Namespace conflict between two S3 methods defined in different R packages

Tags: r, namespaces, lme4

I need advice on how to deal with a namespace conflict. More specifically, two packages I use concurrently define identically named S3 methods for the same generic function. The first package is the `ergm` package; the second one is the `lme4` package. They both define `simulate.formula`.

When I load the `ergm` package but not `lme4`, I can simulate just fine:

```r
library("ergm")
data(florentine)
gest <- ergm(flomarriage ~ edges + absdiff("wealth"))
f <- gest$formula
coefs <- coef(gest)
s <- simulate(f, coef = coefs)
```

If I load the `lme4` package after `ergm`, I get an error:

```r
library("ergm")
library("lme4")
data(florentine)
gest <- ergm(flomarriage ~ edges + absdiff("wealth"))
f <- gest$formula
coefs <- coef(gest)
s <- simulate(f, coef = coefs)
```

> Error in weights(object) : argument "object" is missing, with no
>   default

This is because the `simulate.formula` method in `lme4` is used because the package was loaded last and overwrote the `simulate.formula` method of the `ergm` package.

In my personal use, I can of course just avoid loading `lme4` after `ergm`. However, I use `simulate` in a package and cannot avoid that some users may do so as they don't know better. In fact, I received several inquiries reporting this bug to me.

If this were a function, I would refer to it using `::`. Is there something like this for referring to a method defined in a specific package? If so, does it have to be exported by the package? Or how else can I avoid the namespace conflict?

See also the [discussion on the GitHub repository of `ergm`](https://github.com/statnet/ergm/issues/130).